# variable as command line to call C programming

Tags: python

Hi all I working on python. I have called a c program using

```
import os
cmd = 'gcc a.c -o a'
os.system(cmd)
```

I need to pass two arguments during the execution of c program through python. Passing the arguments is done. But I am unable to pass a variable of p1 which is generated in python code. How to pass a data/string stored in variable as an argument.

```
p1 = word[:int(n_length)]
cmd1 = './a p1 going'
os.system(cmd1)
```

Currently p1 is passed as an argument not the string of p1 is passed. Please hep

Comment: I have tried with `cmd1 = './a $p1 going'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cmd1 = './a {} going'.format(p1)
```

Comment: for passing two variable will it be like `cmd1 = './a {} {}'.format(p1).format(p2)` ??

Comment: @AtanuMandal For two variables it would be `cmd = './a {} {}'.format(p1, p2)`

Comment: @AtanuMandal: For two or more variables, you can use: `cmd = './a {0} {1}'.format(p1, p2)`

`{0}` is the first parameter and `{1}` is the second parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can try do like this:

```
p1 = word[:int(n_length)]
cmd1 = './a ' + str(p1) + ' going' # This appends the value of p1 in the string
os.system(cmd1)
```

Comment: having error `sh: 1: ./aloing: not found` loing is the string present in p1

Comment: Oh sorry, you have to add a space after ./a, I'll edit my answer, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the value inside command string before executing

```
p1 = word[:int(n_length)]
cmd1 = './a {} going'.format(p1)
os.system(cmd1)
```